# mysql запрос

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
EVENT swg.event1
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '3' MINUTE
    STARTS '2013-03-25 18:48:25'
    DO 
BEGIN
  if(select ваш_столбик from ваша_табличка)<100 then
      update ваша_табличка set ваш_столбик=ваш_столбик+1;
    end if;

END
```

**жирный текст**
куда его нужно вставить????

Comment: Чего хочет!? о_О

Comment: Ему нужно вставить жирный текст, он же написал. Но он не знает куда...

Comment: куда этот код нужно вставить??

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin. Выбираешь базу, затем вкладка 'SQL'.
На будущее советую четче формулировать свой вопрос во избежание троллинга и холивара.